# PHP + SQL Script - Protect against SQL Inject

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using unity to pass values to my php script with HTTP GET. I am new to php and just got my script to work, however, I would like to make sure I can protect against SQL Injection. Can someone please look this over and let me know what I need to change in order to protect it?

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Test";
$password = "Test";
$dbname = "Test";

$userId = $_GET['userId'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT rp FROM RP where userID = '$userId'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //echo "UserID: " . $row["userID"]. " - RP: " . $row["rp"]."<br>";
    echo "RP: " . $row["rp"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Don't use `query(` use `prepare` and `execute` and pass the value in the execute. See the link above ^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent sql injections - use prepared statements.
Here's the link:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

**UPDATED**

Example:

```
$id = 5;

$c = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$s = $c->prepare("SELECT * FROM RP WHERE id = ?");
$s->bind_param('s', $id);
$s->execute();
$r = $s->get_result();
$f = $r->fetch_assoc();

echo $f['rp'];
```

**UPDATED**

Example #2:

```
$id = 5;
$rp = "lalala";
$rp2 = "boomboomboom";

$c = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$s = $c->prepare("UPDATE RP SET rp = ?, rp2 = ? WHERE userID = ?");
$s->bind_param('sss', $rp, $rp2, $id);
$s->execute();
```

Comment: How would I make it if I wanted to pass multiple values in the prepare statement? Like a SQL Update statement with the update amount and the userId.

Comment: I updated the answer, but please, follow the link and read all about "prepared statements" and i promise you that most of your questions will disappear.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, you could just check if $_GET['userId'] is numeric with [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php). If it's not, trigger error and exit.

But that's just for simple cases like these. You should read this: [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

What you need is called prepared statements, which in theory, as far as I know, should be impossible to break. 
You will be able to choose between prepared statements in Mysqli and PDO.  It has very, very little flexibility, so my suggestion is to go with the PDO, any day of the week.

Just to clarify - your code is completely prone to injection. All what's needed to do is use a Mysql command in query string, and the script will execute it just like if you wrote it.